# ics file import using webDAV to outlook, user have not permission to add appointments

Tags: outlook, calendar, webdav, outlook-calendar

Please can anyone help me on this.
I'm working on a functionality which help me to sync my website appointments to users outlook calender and then user can add more appointments in his outlook calendar.

I'm using webDAV protocol for this. All is working fine. But issue is that when I'm adding any calendar using "From Internet" option then I'm not able to add new appointment. 
Can anyone help me to solve this issue. May be this is something webdav configration issue.

Comment: Is this a programming question? So you are essentially trying to import an ICS file to Outlook?

Comment: Hi @DmitryStreblechenko thanks for reply, I think this is webDAV configration issue. But not found any clue that what is missing. So, have you any idea, what is missing. When I'm double click on ics file and this file opens in outlook calendar, then in outlook user can add, edit, delete appointments. But in second case, when user import ics file using "Add Calendar" > "From Internet" option from webdav server then user have not any permission except view.

Comment: I still do not understand what you are trying to do. What does this have to do with WebDAV? Outlook does not use it.

Answer (score 0):

What might be happening here is that when you add the `.ics` from disk to Outlook, Outlook doen't have to check any permissions to modify the file. Now when you added from internet, that means that the `.ics` belongs to a calendar provider, which generally implement the [ACL protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3744). This protocol specify some methods to check the permission when a client want to read/modify a calendar.

So when you add the `.ics` you have to specify an `URL` that is the container of the file (generally this `URL` is gonna be the a **Calendar Collection** that belongs to the `CALDAV:calendar-home-set`), so the client sends a `Profind`request to the server asking for the `DAV:current-user-privilege-set` and the definition of this property is:

> DAV:current-user-privilege-set is a protected property containing the
> exact set of privileges (as computed by the server) granted to the
> currently authenticated HTTP user.  Aggregate privileges and their
> contained privileges are listed.  A user-agent can use the value of
> this property to adjust its user interface to make actions
> inaccessible (e.g., by graying out a menu item or button) for which
> the current principal does not have permission.  This property is
> also useful for determining what operations the current principal can
> perform, without having to actually execute an operation.

So after this, Outlook knows that the current principal doesn't have any permission to perform any action on this calendar resource and it just doesn't show any action for the file.

Hope it helps.